# HTML all button is not working, only one button is working

Tags: html, go

I am using go templete to set values in HTML templete but here. I am creating many `<button id="exec" cid="{{.Id}}">Show</button>` using loop but only first button click function is working other it not working. For only first button ajax call happened.

```
  <body >
    <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;float:left;width: 50%">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Country Name</th>
          <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        {{ range .CountryData }}
                <tr>
                      <td>{{ .Name }}</td>
                      <td><button id="exec" cid="{{.Id}}">Show</button></td>
                </tr>
        {{ end }} 
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="response" style="height:700px;overflow:auto;float:left;width: 50%"></div>
</div>
  </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#exec").on("click", function() {
                var urlData = "/country?cid=" + $(this).attr("cid");
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlData,
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` property of elements in html document should be unique, and you you select the element using `$("#exec")` you select only the first element with that id.
You can move to class selectors, or use multiple ids and select by other selector:

```
<body >
    <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="height:700px;overflow:auto;float:left;width: 50%">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Country Name</th>
          <th>View</th>
        </tr>
        {{ range .CountryData }}
                <tr>
                      <td>{{ .Name }}</td>
                      <td><button class="exec" cid="{{.Id}}">Show</button></td>
                </tr>
        {{ end }} 
    </table>
    </div>
    <div id="response" style="height:700px;overflow:auto;float:left;width: 50%"></div>
</div>
  </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button.exec").on("click", function() {
                var urlData = "/country?cid=" + $(this).attr("cid");
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlData,
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If there is no way to change the `id` prop you can add some other classes and use some other selectors. For example - you can add id to the table, and then select all the buttons inside that specific table:

```
<table id="table-with-buttons">
    ...
    {{ range .CountryData }}
            <tr>
                  <td>{{ .Name }}</td>
                  <td><button id="exec" cid="{{.Id}}">Show</button></td>
            </tr>
    {{ end }} 
</table>
```

And inside your code you can select all the buttons using:

```
$("#table-with-buttons button").on("click", function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Is there any way using one id for multiple button to solve this problem ?

Comment: @KmarlonPereira you can use key, value inside a range like range $i, $a := .CountryData and use like <button class="exec{{$i}}" ...

Comment: @KmarlonPereira check the update on the answer. Keep in mind that regardless - I would change the structure to **not have multiple elements with the same id**.